# Tensorflow - Reloading model and being able to continue updating it

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to save model/graph and reload it in another file. However, I would also like to be able to continue updating model in the new file. So far I have successfully reloaded things like outputs from neural networks, but I am not able to update networks.

I have tried this but it can't even compile.

```
tf.identity(self.train_pi_op, name="train_pi_op")
tf.identity(self.train_value_op, name="train_value_op")
tf.identity(self.target_update, name="target_update")
```

I need to reload these:

```
self.train_pi_op = self.pi_optimizer.minimize(self.pi_loss, var_list=get_vars('main/pi'))
with tf.control_dependencies([self.train_pi_op]):
    self.train_value_op = self.value_optimizer.minimize(self.value_loss, var_list=self.value_params)
with tf.control_dependencies([self.train_value_op]):
    self.target_update = tf.group([tf.assign(self.v_targ, self.polyak * self.v_targ + (1 - self.polyak) * self.v_main)
                                for self.v_main, self.v_targ in zip(get_vars('main'), get_vars('target'))])
```

Could someone point me into the right direction? If its possible, is possible to save somehow weights and biases and reuse them in a different file? Also I ve read somewhere that the AdamOptimizer has its own parameters (that change over time) and so I believe that I cannot rewrite it or is that wrong?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think that I ve solved it with just simply naming it:

```
self.train_pi_op = self.pi_optimizer.minimize(self.pi_loss, var_list=get_vars('main/pi'), name="train_pi_op")
```

and from the other program I ve called that with

```
self.train_pi_op = self.graph.get_operation_by_name("train_pi_op")
```